# Connection error when deploying chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I just started using chaincode.

I am following step by step:
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#running-the-chaincode

I am using Docker toolbox on Windows.

But when I start to run chaincode_example02, I get the following errors:

```
2016/09/15 14:05:53 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: connectex: The requested address is not valid in its context."; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
2016/09/15 14:05:54 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: connectex: The requested address is not valid in its context."; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
2016/09/15 14:05:55 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: connectex: The requested address is not valid in its context."; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
```

Why?

Comment: please post all the steps that you have followed along with all the outputs.

Comment: yes, please help us understand how you set up your environment.